# $p$ | $2n\choose n$ if there exists a positive integer $j$ with $n < p^j\leq 2n$

Tags: number-theory

If there exists a positive integer $j$ with $n < p^j\leq 2n$ then $p\mid$  ${2n}\choose {n}$

I tried something but I can't able to prove, the numerator has more prime power than the denominator. please give me a hint to start with.

Comment: $v_p({2n \choose n}) = \sum_{k \ge 1} \left[\lfloor \frac{2n}{p^k}\rfloor - 2\lfloor \frac{n}{p^k}\rfloor\right]$

Comment: @mathworker21 $v_p({2n \choose n}) = \sum_{k \ge 1} \left[\lfloor \frac{2n}{p^k}\rfloor - 2\lfloor \frac{n}{p^k}\rfloor\right] \geq 0 $ how to prove it is atleast 1

Comment: use what you're given in problem statement. try to figure it out for a bit

Comment: [Kummer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer%27s_theorem) gives this immediately. There will be a carry  to the most significant base $p$ digit when you add $n+n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $n < p^{j} \leq 2n$, it is clear that $\bigl[\frac{n}{p^j}\bigr]=0$. Also since $n<p^{j}$, $2n < 2p^{j} \le p^{j+1}$ which gives $\bigl[\frac{2n}{p^j}\bigr]=1$, which gives us $\bigl[\frac{2n}{p^j}\bigr]-2\bigl[\frac{n}{p^j}\bigr]=1$. So $$v_{p}\left(\binom{2n}{n}\right)=\sum_{\substack{k\geq 1 \\ k\neq i}} \left\{\left[\frac{2n}{2^k}\right]-2\left[\frac{n}{p^k}\right]\right\} + \biggl[\frac{2n}{p^j}\biggr]-2\biggl[\frac{n}{p^j}\biggr] \geq 1$$

Comment: Your answer was written very poorly (with all due respect). I hope you don't mind me editing it to make the writing better.

Comment: Emm. I don't understand what was poor with my answer. Also i don't recognize your edited part.